# How can I find the normal vector (or the handle) of the triangle that a ray intersects?

Tags: c++, 3d, intersection, cgal, aabb

I have a ray and number of 3D points that I triangulate and feed into an AABBtree, which allows me to find the intersection of the ray with the mesh.
Now I would also like to know the normal vector of the triangle that the ray intersects.

I project the points into the x-y plane and apply Delaunay meshing. I then feed the 3D points into to AABBtree structure. Ideally I don't want to change this part.

Finding the intersection with  first_intersection() is straightforward.
How do I find the normal of the intersected triangle?

edit: The roblem is, that `boost::get<KernelSCD::Point_3>(&(intersection->first))` only gives me the actual intersection point. In order to find the normal vector to the intersected triangle I need the handle of the intersected triangle. How do I get this?

This is my code:

```
// CGAL includes for AABB tree for intersection detection
#include <CGAL/AABB_tree.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_traits.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_triangle_primitive.h>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>

// CGAL includes for Delaunay triangulation
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/compute_normal.h>

#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_tree.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_traits.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/compute_normal.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/orientation.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> KernelSCD;
    typedef KernelSCD::Triangle_3 Triangle_3;
    typedef std::list<Triangle_3>::iterator IteratorTriangle;
    typedef CGAL::AABB_triangle_primitive<KernelSCD, IteratorTriangle> Primitive;
    typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<KernelSCD, Primitive> AABB_triangle_traits;
    typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<AABB_triangle_traits> Tree;
    typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
    typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned, K>    Vb;
    typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb>                    Tds;
    typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, Tds>                      Delaunay;
    typedef Delaunay::Point                                             PointD;
    typedef Delaunay::Vertex_handle                                     Vertex_handle;
    typedef KernelSCD::Point_3 Point_3;
    typedef KernelSCD::Vector_3 Vector_3;
    typedef KernelSCD::Ray_3 Ray_3; 
    typedef boost::optional<Tree::Intersection_and_primitive_id<Ray_3>::Type> Ray_intersection;
    typedef Tree::Primitive_id AABB_primitive_id;


    Delaunay dt;
    std::vector< std::pair<PointD, unsigned> > points_2d;
    std::vector<Point_3> points_3d;

    Tree tree_3d_map_;
    std::list<Triangle_3> triangles_;

    std::vector<double> verts = { 0,  0, 100,
                                  0,  1, 101,
                                  1,  0, 102,
                                  1,  1, 103,
                                 10,  0, 104,
                                  0, 10, 105,
                                 10, 10, 106};

    // Filling Delaunay triangulation
    for (int i = 0; i+2 < verts.size(); i += 3) {
        points_2d.push_back(std::make_pair(PointD(verts.at(i), verts.at(i + 1)), i / 3));
        points_3d.push_back(Point_3(verts.at(i), verts.at(i + 1), verts.at(i + 2)));
    }
    dt.insert(points_2d.begin(), points_2d.end());

    // Filling AABB tree
    int v0, v1, v2;
    for (Delaunay::Finite_faces_iterator it = dt.finite_faces_begin(); it != dt.finite_faces_end(); it++){
        v0 = it->vertex(0)->info();
        v1 = it->vertex(1)->info();
        v2 = it->vertex(2)->info();
        triangles_.push_back(Triangle_3(points_3d.at(v0), points_3d.at(v1), points_3d.at(v2)));
    }
    tree_3d_map_.insert(triangles_.begin(), triangles_.end());

    Point_3 p1(.4, .5, 0.1);
    Vector_3 v(0, 0, 1);
    Ray_3 ray(p1, v);

    // Find point where the ray intersects the mesh for the first time
    Ray_intersection intersection = tree_3d_map_.first_intersection(ray);

    if (intersection){
        if (boost::get<KernelSCD::Point_3>(&(intersection->first))){
            const KernelSCD::Point_3* p = boost::get<KernelSCD::Point_3>(&(intersection->first));
            std::cout << "First intersection: " << p->x() << ", " << p->y() << ", " << p->z() << std::endl;

            AABB_primitive_id primitive_id = intersection->second;
            //                                                                             Fails: 
            //                                                                           |  |  |  | 
            //                                                                           v  v  v  v  
            //KernelSCD::Vector_3 v = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::compute_face_normal(primitive_id,points_3d); 
            //std::cout << "v: " << v.x() << ", " << v.y() << ", " << v.z() << std::endl;
        }
    }       


    /* If I use a Surface_mesh, it works:
    typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point_3> Mesh;
    typedef CGAL::AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive<Mesh> PrimitiveM;
    typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<KernelSCD, PrimitiveM> Traits;
    typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<Traits> TreeM;
    typedef boost::optional<TreeM::Intersection_and_primitive_id<Ray_3>::Type> Ray_intersectionM;
    typedef TreeM::Primitive_id AABB_primitive_idM;

    std::ifstream input("tetrahedron.off");
    Mesh mesh;
    input >> mesh;
    TreeM tree;
    tree.insert(faces(mesh).first, faces(mesh).second, mesh);
    Ray_intersectionM intersection2 = tree.first_intersection(ray);
    if (intersection2){
        if (boost::get<Point_3>(&(intersection2->first))){
            const Point_3* p = boost::get<Point_3>(&(intersection2->first));
            std::cout << "First intersection: " << *p << std::endl;

            AABB_primitive_idM primitive_id = intersection2->second;

            // Works: 
            Vector_3 v = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::compute_face_normal(primitive_id,mesh); 
            std::cout << "v: " << v.x() << ", " << v.y() << ", " << v.z() << std::endl;
        }
    }*/

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are global functions `normal` and `unit_normal` and kernel functors `Construct_normal_3` and `Construct_unit_normal_3` which all take 3 points and may be relevant.

Comment: The problem is I don't have the 3 points. 
My guess is, the way to go is to obtain the handle of the intersected triangle, which will lead to the 3 corners. Or I can use the function compute_face_normal() or one of the functions you mentioned. In either case I need the handle of the intersected triangle. How do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've missed something, but isn't that the application of simple vector mathematics ? if you know the 3 points of your triangle, you can create a vector from point[0] to point[1] and from point[0] to point[2] and do the cross product. The result will be a vector that is **perpendicular** to both your vectors (the **normal** of your triangle).

Comment: That's correct. The problem is that I don't have these 3 points.  
How do I find these 3 points?